# abelian group, direct summand

Tags: modules, abelian-groups, exact-sequence, direct-sum

Let $G$ be an abelian group, and $H$ and $N$ is a subgroup. And assume 
$$
G / H \cong N \ .
$$
Are these assumptions sufficient to show that $G$ is direct sum of H and N?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: $\Bbb Z/4 \to \Bbb Z/2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is a counter example.

$H=N= \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$, $G = \mathbb{Z}/ 4 \mathbb{Z}$.